# ajax script not updating information

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am trying to make an ajax script to automatically refresh the amount of in-game money a user has on my site however, it's not working.
I am not very good with ajax so i have definitely done something wrong, if anyone could help me out I would highley appreciate it.

Here is my code:

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function($) {
      $.ajaxSetup({
          cache: false,
          beforeSend: function() {
            $('#money').show();
          },
          complete: function() {
            $('#money').show();
          },
          success: function() {
            $('#money').show();
          });
        var $container = $("#money"); $container.load("challenges.php?money=<?php echo $_SESSION['Money'];?>");
        var refreshID = setInterval(function() {
          $container.load("challenges.php?money=<?php echo $_SESSION['Money'];?>");
        }, 1000);
      });
  })(jQuery);
</script>
```

**PHP part**

```
<?php
    echo "<div id='money'>Balance: $".$_SESSION['Money']." ||</div> ";
?>
```

`$_SESSION['Money']` is equal to the users amount of money.
I have been sat trying to figure this out for ages now. If you need any more information let me know. I want to do this so the users don't need to refresh the page to see their balance. I tried to follow a tutorial for part of it but I got lost and I'm really no good with ajax. Any help is highley appreciated.

Comment: You probably meant to use `$.ajax()` instead of `$.ajaxSetup()`

Comment: Your Javascript is totally broken, please fix the brackets.

Comment: @BoltKey I've changed it yet it still doesn't work.. I'm such a noob with this...

Comment: could you post your updated ajax?

Comment: @Alex I don't even know what to change. I've just changed what BoltKey said at the top ($.ajaxSetup())->$.ajax. I'm new with this, but it's vital I get it working on my website...

Answer (score 2):

`$.load()` can take an optional callback parameter, see http://api.jquery.com/load/

You probably want to do this:

```
(function($) {
    var $container = $("#money");

    function do_load(){
      $container.load("challenges.php?money=<?php echo $_SESSION['Money'];?>", function(){
          // show the container when loading is complete
          $container.show();
      });
    }

    do_load();
    var refreshID = setInterval(do_load, 1000);
})(jQuery);
```

---

Completely rewritten and assuming PHP will return JSON:

HTML:

```
Balance: <span id="money"></span>
```

JS:

```
(function($) {
    var $container = $("#money");

    function do_load(){
      $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "challenges.php?money=<?php echo $_SESSION['Money'];?>",
      }).done(function(data) {
        // write the value of balance to the container
        console.log("Server returned:", data);
        $container.html(data);
      }).error(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ){
          console.log("Server returned an error:", textStatus, errorThrown );
          console.log("jqXHR:", jqXHR);
      });
    };

    do_load();
    var refreshID = setInterval(function(){
        do_load();
    }, 1000);

})(jQuery);
```

PHP:

```
<?php
    // @TODO: fill your session variable (from a file / database / ...)
    $_SESSION['Money'] = rand(0, 100000); 
    echo $_SESSION['Money'];
?>
```

Comment: Right okay so this looks like something that should work. But from my average PHP knowledge, it looks like `challenges.php?money=` is GET? Will it matter that I am using POST for everything, because I've tried this and it doesn't work...

Comment: Sorry, it's been some time since I've last coded in PHP, but you're right, `$.load()` will send a GET to the server, that maybe needs to be handled differently than a POST.  - and oh, I just noticed, `#money` only exists after the fist `load`.

Comment: So what do I need to do differently due to it being POST, do you know? Also, do I need to change were #money is then? Or add it anywhere else?

Comment: I've updated the answer with a POST example. And yes, your HTML container must exist before you can manipulate it.

Comment: I really appreciate this help man, but it's still not updating... I've made sure its in the right order, however when change the amount of money in the database, it still doesn't change until I refresh the page..

Comment: Could be a problem with the way I've written the `setInterval` -> changed. Or maybe your server does not update the content of the session variable? I've added a `console.log` to the ajax call - you should be able to see if the function gets called every second and see what the server returns. Or is it a matter of case-sensitive? your Session var is called `Money` and the url param is lowercase `money`. Like I said, PHP is not my strong side.

Comment: The console isn't returning anything, which is strange. I've tried changing it to upper-case and visa-verse, no change. Also POST, unlike GET doesn't pass anything through the URL, right??

Comment: What if you return a randon int instead of the session variable? That way you can narrow down the problem to either JS or PHP: `echo '{ "balance": "'.rand(0,100000).'" }';`

Comment: Tried that, still no logs in the console unfortunately.

Comment: added error handler to ajax call. if this still doesn't log anythig I'm out of ideas, sorry

Comment: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input`

Comment: Sounds like a JSON parse error. Are you sure, you're returning valid JSON from the server, as described in my example? It's important that the JSON key and value (at least if it' a string) are wrapped in double quotes, not single quotes. You should be able to see what the server returns in your browser's console `Network` tab. Either way, I'll try to dumb down the example, let's try a string instead of JSON.

Comment: I don't know if I am or not, I only started trying to do this before I'd never come across it before... I don't get where I'm meant to update this random number thats been set as the session? Ive made a new session for money in another file like the TODO says and I've changed it, however nothing changes even when I refresh another random number generates..